# @font-face fonts not working

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to get a font working from local storage.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: const;
    src: url(const.ttf);
}

.fp_title1 {
    font-family: 'const', trebuchet ms;
    font-size: 350%;
    font-weight: 100;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px;
}
```

This won't work. I've tried renaming the file, using the 'font-family' with and without quotes...

I've also tried to link the font with HTML

```
<link href='CSS/const.ttf' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

It's in the same folder, the name is right. I don't get it.

**EDIT:** My CSS file is already linked, the font is .ttf

Comment: you gave wrong path for css. Change it to href='Css/const.css'

Comment: i tested in my local. it is working fine. put the jsfiddle link so that we can test it.

Comment: @Ullas My CSS file is already linked. The font is .ttf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have 2 mistakes in code: path and extention. And use the following formats as well as ttf:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'const';
  src: url('const.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('const.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('const.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('const.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('const.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

urls that helps to create web fonts:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

http://www.font-face-generator.com/

Comment: You migh twanna push the .svg further up in line if you want chrome to use it instead of .woff

Comment: Yes, exactly!  +1 for your findings :)

Comment: @KunJ It says my font is corrupted... Windows Font Viewer however shows it properly, and I downloaded the font from the official source. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bn92i29t5345kju/Construhinvism%20-%20Free%20Font%20%5B%20www.iampedrofernandes.com%20%5D.zip)

Comment: I have tried it many times earlier and just tried with arial.ttf and it gave me perfect result. May be your font have some glyphs that are corrupted.

Comment: Let me check it with your font.

Comment: Yes, you were right! Try this url ( http://www.font-face-generator.com/ ), its working. I added it in answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS has a `.css` filename extension, you gave it `.ttf`

Comment: But it's a .ttf file?

Comment: No. The font you link into your css is a .ttf. The css-file is still a .css.
Much like you would link in an image as a background in css.